# Possibility for GIS.SE podcasts or competitions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, conference

I was curious what the community thought of having either a GIS specific podcast or gis competition. Both can happen online and both would help in building a community base, ultimately giving us more users and answers with more quality as a result. The community would gain knowledge with either item, and it would also attract new users who are interested in the topic of GIS. Currently the SE podcasts are just ramblings on the life of the general SE community and creators. My thoughts are that more potential users would be attracted to SE, if category specific events are created, this may help in gaining more interest for GIS.SE. The reason that SE isn't one big site was to accomplish what I am alluding to. I feel that one or both of these would be beneficial to this community and ultimately improve the answers and questions we get on GIS.SE. The ultimate goal of the SE community is to reduce the noise when searching for an effective solution to a question when searching for a quality answer on the web. These two items would specifically increase the footprint of GIS.SE, improve the quality of the GIS.SE community, and raise interest in SE overall. These two items both require work to incorporate, but I feel they would be beneficial to the SE community.

**Question:** What does everyone think about having either GIS.SE specific podcast or competitions?

Comment: Both would increase knowledge of current and potential SE community, ultimately improving quality of answers/solutions to questions.

Answer (score 2):

Well, we can certainly have a guest from GIS -- a notable community member -- on the Stack Exchange podcast.

We did this before with http://diy.stackexchange.com in Podcast #10:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/se-podcast-10/

You'll have to listen for yourself to determine how you think it went, but I say it worked and was interesting!

Therefore, I am open to more site-specific guest podcasts throughout the network, it's just a matter of lining them up and making sure it's not *too* nichey to be interesting to a somewhat broader audience of listeners.

Comment: Well I listened to the podcast and it was great. I think that those type podcasts should happen a lot more. You were right it did work. You guys should have him do his own podcast on DIY he was great!

Comment: On a separate note maybe you guys could invite James Fee sometime I saw that he had joined SE.